# Weka GUI - Not enough memory, won't load?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka

This same installation of Weka has loaded for me in the past.  I am simply trying to load the Weka GUI (double click on the icon) and I get the following error.  How can I fix it?

```
OutOfMemory
Not enough memory.  Please load a smaller dataset or use a larger heap size.
- initial JVM size: 122.4 MB
- total memory used: 165.3 MB
- max. memory avail.: 227.6 MB

Note:
The Java heap size can be specified with the -Xmx option.
etc..
```

I am not loading Weka from the command line, so how can I stop this from occurring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you were able to use it before but not now.  However, you can specify a larger heap size by changing the `RunWeka.ini` configuration file.  On a Windows machine it should be in the Weka folder of your Program Files directory.  You could try a line specifying, for example,

```
maxheap=200m
```

There might already be such an option in that file that you can simply change to a larger number.

Comment: I know this is old, but any idea how to do it on a Mac? Thanks!

Comment: I assume there is some analogous folder and config file, but unfortunately I don't know exactly where that is on a Mac.

Answer (score 16):

Just write an answer here for ubuntu users.

If you `apt-get install weka`, you will have a script installed at `/usr/bin/weka`
The first a few lines look like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /usr/lib/java-wrappers/java-wrappers.sh

# default options
CLASS="weka.gui.GUIChooser"
MEMORY="256m"
GUI=""
```

Just modify the line starts with `MEMORY` so that you have larger upper bound.

```
MEMORY="2048m"
```

Comment: This works, thanks.  It also takes `g` notation, as in `MEMORY="2g"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it on Mac:

- right-click on the main Weka file (that opens the Gui) and select "Show Package Contents";
- open Info.plist file with any text editor;
- change the -Xmx option.

viola