# Not enough memory for weka GUI

Tags: java, memory, weka

I'm new to weka and am just playing around with it. On a Unix computer, I type

```
weka
```

and the correct GUI shows up for about 4-5 seconds (note that this happens during any directory I type this, so I'm not sure if I'm calling it from the right one). But during this time the memory must exceed the max heap size:

```
Not enough memory. Please load a smaller dataset or use larger heap size.
- initial JVM size: 119.1MB
- total memory used: 160.3MB
- max. memory avail.:  227.6 MB
```

My problem is similar to the one here [ [Weka GUI - Not enough memory, won't load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164638/weka-gui-not-enough-memory-wont-load) ] but I'm not using a Window's computer, so I'm not sure how to permanently change the max heap memory. This has happened every time I try to open weka.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not trying to load any data nor use the simpleCLI; I'm just trying to get the GUI to show up and explore what it has to offer, so I'm not sure if I need to use

```
java -Xmx1024MB
```

Or anything like that.

Comment: Is `weka` a startup script you can read to see what environment variables it uses or can you change the the script?  Given the maximum is usually 1/4 of the maximum memory on 64-bit systems, it sounds like you might need a larger system. How much memory does it have?

Comment: No, I just wasn't sure what the correct command was to open the GUI up. I guess I do need java -Xmx1024m ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the command below. You might have to adjust the amount of memory according to the size of your dataset.

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar weka.jar
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks! I didn't know I needed to use the weka.jar file.

Comment: Just another note for anyone else finding this: I'd tried java -jar -Xmx1024m weka.jar and that ordering didn't work. ialencar's version did.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick-fix for Mac users, that doesn't involve Terminal:

right-click on the main Weka file (that opens the Gui) and select "Show Package Contents";
open Info.plist file with any text editor;
change the -Xmx option.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [optimizing memory limit for Weka](http://invictium.wordpress.com/2008/02/26/weka-353-and-jvm-with-14-16-gb-memory-limit-workaround/).